# Why unitary principal series is unitary?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, automorphic-forms

I am reading the book [representation theory of semisimple groups](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/795.html). On page 33, I tried to verify that $\mathcal{P}^{k,iv}$ is unitary. We need to verify that
$$
\left|\left| \mathcal{P}^{k,iv}\left(\begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right)f \right|\right| = ||f||, \quad f \in L^2(\mathbb{C}).
$$
We have 
\begin{align}
& \left|\left| \mathcal{P}^{k,iv}\left(\begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right)f \right|\right| \\
& = \int_{\mathbb{C}} |-bz+d|^{-2-iv} (\frac{-bz+d}{|-bz+d|})^{-k} f(\frac{az-c}{-bz+d}) \overline{|-bz+d|^{-2-iv} (\frac{-bz+d}{|-bz+d|})^{-k} f(\frac{az-c}{-bz+d}) } dz \\
& = \int_{\mathbb{C}} |-bz+d|^{-4}   f(\frac{az-c}{-bz+d}) \overline{  f(\frac{az-c}{-bz+d}) } dz.
\end{align}
How to show that 
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{C}} |-bz+d|^{-4}   f(\frac{az-c}{-bz+d}) \overline{  f(\frac{az-c}{-bz+d}) } dz = \int_{\mathbb{C}} f(z) \overline{  f(z) } dz?
\end{align}

Let 
$$
z_1 = \frac{az-c}{-bz+d}.
$$
Then
$$
z  = \frac{c+z_1d}{a+z_1b}.
$$
We have 
$$
dz = \frac{1}{(a+z_1b)^2}dz_1, \\
|-bz+d| = |a+z_1b|^{-1}.
$$
Therefore 
\begin{align}
& \int_{\mathbb{C}} |-bz+d|^{-4}   f(\frac{az-c}{-bz+d}) \overline{  f(\frac{az-c}{-bz+d}) } dz = \int_{\mathbb{C}} f(z) \overline{  f(z) } dz \\
& = \int_{\mathbb{C}} |-bz+d|^{-4}   f(\frac{az-c}{-bz+d}) \overline{  f(\frac{az-c}{-bz+d}) } dz = \int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{|a+z_1b|^4}{(a+z_1b)^2} f(z_1) \overline{  f(z_1) } dz_1. 
\end{align}
But I didn't get 
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{C}} |-bz+d|^{-4}   f(\frac{az-c}{-bz+d}) \overline{  f(\frac{az-c}{-bz+d}) } dz = \int_{\mathbb{C}} f(z) \overline{  f(z) } dz.
\end{align}

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[image]